# .NET CORE Webpage locks up when (async) loading large amount of images (from AWS S3)

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I'm building a .NET Core web-app (using razor pages) with a gallery section that displays a large amount of images. I'd like to lazy load these pictures so as not to completely freeze up the page when I open it. However, despite awaiting all methods, the page still freezes, then after a few seconds opens with all images loaded.

**This is the code I use to retrieve image from Amazon AWS S3 service**

```
public async Task<byte[]> ReturnImageAsByteArray(string storageKey)
    {
        GetObjectResponse response;

        response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(BUCKET_NAME, storageKey);

        if(response == null)
        {
            response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(BUCKET_NAME, IMG_NOT_FOUND_KEY);
            Console.WriteLine("S3 Service: returned null for image with: " + storageKey);
        }
        
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
        {
            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        }

        var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        return bytes;
    }
```

**This method is called by the OnGet() method of the page loading the images, like so. It converts the byte array to base64 strings.**

```
 public async Task<string> LoadImageFromKey(string key)
    {
        byte[] imageByteArray;

        try
        {
            imageByteArray = await _imageService.ReturnImageAsByteArray(key);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
       
        if (imageByteArray == null)
            return "";

        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteArray);
        var formatted = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);

        return formatted;
    }
```

**That method in turn is called by the HTML front-end of the page, like so;**

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.SnapshotModel)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @{
                string img = await Model.LoadImageFromKey(item.ImageS3Key); 
            }
            <img loading="lazy" src="@img" style="width: auto;height:50px" />

        ...... (cut short for brevity)
```

Please note that the images I'm loading from AWS S3 are +/- 600KB each, so not large at all. I thought that because I awaited all methods, the UI wouldn't lock up but rather lazily load in all the pictures. Can someone tell me where the mistake in my code is so I can get it to load without freezing the page first?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing now is asynchronously loading all the images server-side before sending the complete page to the client. You need to separate the generation of the image source URL from the image fetching.

For example, if the path to the image should be `/images/{imageId}` and a request to that address works on its own, just put that as the `src` and you'll be all set

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that all images are saved to the S3 service, and thus are not in any directory on the server itself. This also means that there is no 'path' to that image other than an API call to fetch that particular image from S3. Any thoughts?

Comment: Create a route-able path that proxies the request so that it looks like your server is hosting the image - basically give `LoadImageFromKey` an accessible route